# How to get specified attributes from an xml column in Sqlserver

Tags: xml, xquery-sql

I have a xml column called MesssageContent in my db as:

```
<ns1:ProductAvailabilityPublication xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com/Ecommerce/Worldwide/AvailabilityService/Schemas/ProductResponse" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/Ecommerce/Worldwide/AvailabilityService/Schemas/ProductRequest" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/Ecommerce/Worldwide/AvailabilityService/Schemas/ProductAvailabilityPublish" RequestorID="WCS_AU" BatchID="36dae836-cc16-489c-8009-afab63f92dff">
  <ns0:ProductResponse ProductNumber="C8010A" LeadTime="1" LastUpdated="2014-07-18T11:17:47.677" Region="AP" CountryCode="AU" CurrInv="259" FutureInv="0" CurrEDD="TBA" FutureEDD="TBA" ETA="0" D-Flag="True">
    <ns0:ProductType>
      <ns2:NonStartingPoint />
    </ns0:ProductType>
    <ns0:Status>
      <ns0:Success />
    </ns0:Status>
  </ns0:ProductResponse>
  <ns0:ProductResponse ProductNumber="Q3655A" LeadTime="1" LastUpdated="2014-07-18T11:17:47.677" Region="AP" CountryCode="AU" CurrInv="2" FutureInv="0" CurrEDD="TBA" FutureEDD="TBA" ETA="0" D-Flag="True">
    <ns0:ProductType>
      <ns2:NonStartingPoint />
    </ns0:ProductType>
    <ns0:Status>
      <ns0:Success />
    </ns0:Status>
  </ns0:ProductResponse>
  <ns0:ProductResponse ProductNumber="PP654A" LeadTime="21" LastUpdated="2014-07-18T11:17:47.677" Region="AP" CountryCode="AU" CurrInv="0" FutureInv="0" CurrEDD="TBA" FutureEDD="TBA" ETA="0" D-Flag="False">
    <ns0:ProductType>
      <ns2:NonStartingPoint />
    </ns0:ProductType>
    <ns0:Status>
      <ns0:Success />
    </ns0:Status>
  </ns0:ProductResponse>

</ns1:ProductAvailabilityPublication>
```

Now I want to find out all "ProductNumber" in  "CurrInv">0 and "D-flag"="True" records. I tried but only can find out the whole xml colomn which with not needed data included. Is it possible to figure out all "ProductNumber" to meet my expression?

Comment: How people supposed to know where ProductNumber, CurrInv, and D-flag you're talking about are located? Post sample XML and explain based on that sample to make your question understandable.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to add line break in the code as I add code markdown but there isn't any line break at all.

Comment: You would do better to just post the XML, indented 4 spaces using the `{}` tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XQuery should work. You need to bind the correct namespaces (or use the namespace wildcard `*` instead of the specific namespaces):

```
//ns0:ProductResponse[@CurrInv > 0][@D-Flag = "True"]/@ProductNumber/string()
```